Flutter Firebase Apple Sign In missing Email/Name on iOS
I'm unable to retrieve email or name using Firebase Auth with AppleAuthProvider on iOS. Did not try on Android or Web.
Environment:

Flutter: 3.22.2
firebase_core: ^3.1.1
firebase_auth: ^5.1.1
Firebase SDK: 10.27.0
iOS Simulator: iOS 17.5

Repository class
static Future<UserCredential> signInWithApple() async {
   final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
   appleProvider.addScope('email');
   appleProvider.addScope('name');
   return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
}

Controller class
Future<void> appleSignIn() async {
   try {
     final credential = await AuthenticationRepository.signInWithApple();
     print(credential.additionalUserInfo);
   } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
     return Future.error(e);
   }
}

I've followed the instructions from Firebase Federated identity page for Flutter. I continue to get the basic popup "Do you want to sign in to APP_NAME with your Apple ID "..email.."?.
On the first time logging in I forgot to add the email scope. Next I did the following (based on many questions answered from stack overflow):

Deleted the user with empty email from Firebase Authentication
Settings -> Password & Security -> Sign in with Apple -> APP_NAME -> Stop using Apple ID

Still no luck. Then I stopped the app, flutter clean && flutter pub get, cd ios, rm -rf Podfile.lock, pod install --repo-update, then run. Still same thing as above.
Next, I deleted the app and did the process all over again. Still no luck.

Does this answer help?

@AlexMamo unfortunately no, I've followed the steps from that page as described in my question. The accepted answer in that page is the same as many other accepted answers from similar questions.

Apparently you will only get the user's name in the first call. Quoting this thread

This behaves correctly, user info is only sent in the ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential upon initial user sign up. Subsequent logins to your app using Sign In with Apple with the same account do not share any user info and will only return a user identifier in the ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential. It is recommened that you securely cache the initial ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential containing the user info until you can validate that an account has succesfully been created on your server.

